# Node - Select one variable from await result return inline

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Lets say I have a function that returns the following:

```
{
  someVar: someVal,
  rows: [1,2,3]
}
```

When using async await, I can do this to get rows only directly into a variable, but it has the same name:

```
var {rows} = await myFunction
```

Or assign it to a result variable then assign rows to be result.rows, but is there a way to assign the result to a variable with a different name in one line, something like:

```
var result = await myFunction.rows
```

sometimes the variable I'm assigning to is declared somewhere else with a different name, or this would be a sub property of an object like:

```
result.rows = await myFunciton.rows
```

Thanks

Comment: `result.rows = (await myFunction).rows`?

Comment: Tried that, it does not work, I get a name is not defined error

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use destructure renaming:

```
const { rows: myRows } = await myFunction();
```

Or if `myRows` is already declared:

```
let myRows = [];

{ rows: myRows } = await myFunction();
```